# Elixir - How can I return a value that can be picked up by another function through the iex console?

Tags: elixir

New to Elixir, I'm trying to write a simple game that will have a readFrom/1 function that reads inputs and plays the game accordingly, and then a print/1 function that will print that game.

Since they will be called through the iex one after the other, how can I make the print/1 function print the result from readFrom/1? In any other language I would just save the values I need in variables and just get them after with the print/1 function.

I have to do it this way due to requirements, and I can't find anything that will help me figure this out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a pipe:

```
iex> args |> readFrom() |> print()
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks.
Following up, how can I include this in my actual module? I'm required to have the program run with only the readFrom("-input-") and then a print() calls from the iex, but the pipe has to be inside the module.

I tried adding `game_object |> print()` (inside the readFrom/1), but I'm not sure how I can accept the other end inside the print() function, as it takes in no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your script from iex by simply adding the script name on the iex command line, like so:

```
$iex myscript.exs
```